Ransack query is returning wrong quantity of objects
I have this ransack query:
SchoolTeacher.ransack(school_classrooms_id_eq: 1134).result.count
it should filter objects of SchoolTeacher where classroom_id os 1134.
SchoolTeacher belongs_to School.
School has_many Classrooms.
it should return 1 object, but returns 923, it is like the query is ignored and is returning to me all the objects of a certain school.
I tried to write this code using where, but returns the same quantity
SchoolTeacher.joins(school: :classrooms).where(classrooms: { id: 1134 }).count

Based on your explanation the query is SELECT school_teachers FROM school_teachers INNER JOIN schools on schools.id = school_teachers.school_id INNER JOIN classrooms ON classrooms.school_id = schools.id WHERE classrooms.id = 1134 this will filter to a single classroom which will filter to a single school which will return every teacher for that school. If SchoolTeacher.joins(school: :classrooms).where(classrooms: { id: 1134 }).count returns 923 then that is the result set and has nothing to do with ransack. It seems maybe you are missing a relationship between teacher and classroom?
